# Create new Array from array of objects with keys of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have one array of objects "cars"

```
let cars = [
{id: 1, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2015'},
{id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2000'},
{id: 3, name: 'BMW', year: '2010'},
{id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
{id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
{id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
{id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
{id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
{id: 5, name: 'Volvo', year: '2012'},
{id: 6, name: 'Volvo', year: '2014'},
{id: 7, name: 'Volvo', year: '2010'},
{id: 8, name: 'Toyota', year: '2012'},
{id: 8, name: 'Jeep', year: '2011'},
];
```

and one object which contains the quantity of cars

```
let obj = {
BMW: 6,
Jeep: 1,
Mercedes: 2,
Toyota: 1,
Volvo: 3,
}
```

I need to create new array from cars which will have only one copy of object in it and add the "quantity" property to appropriate object. How can I achieve this?

expected output.

```
newArray = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2015', quantity: 2},
    {id: 3, name: 'BMW', year: '2010', quantity: 6},
    {id: 5, name: 'Volvo', year: '2012', quantity: 3},
    {id: 8, name: 'Toyota', year: '2012', quantity: 1},
    {id: 8, name: 'Jeep', year: '2011', quantity: 1},
]
```

Comment: what do you mean by one copy of object in it ?

Comment: can you give an example of the output you expect? Currently, it's unclear whether you want unique objects by id or by name

Comment: I mean only one item with the same name property

Comment: So, for example, you have 2 Mercedes objects: one for 2015 and one for 2000. You also have a Mercedes quantity of 2. How do you know which model year has which quantity? If you only want one property per unique name property, then you'd just get the quantity object you listed.

Comment: what about `id` and `year` in the new objects?

Comment: id and year they are not important in this case.
I edited the code with expected example

Comment: is the count always from the actual array?

Comment: @NinaScholz count I get from cars array

Answer (score 2):

You could count directly by using the array with a hash table.

```js
let cars = [{ id: 1, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2015' }, { id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2000' }, { id: 3, name: 'BMW', year: '2010' }, { id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004' }, { id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004' }, { id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004' }, { id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004' }, { id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004' }, { id: 5, name: 'Volvo', year: '2012' }, { id: 6, name: 'Volvo', year: '2014' }, { id: 7, name: 'Volvo', year: '2010' }, { id: 8, name: 'Toyota', year: '2012' }, { id: 8, name: 'Jeep', year: '2011' }],
    result = Object.values(cars.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.name] = r[o.name] || { ... o, quantity: 0 };
        r[o.name].quantity++;
        return r;
    }, []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new array with all the items from `cars` object and the count from `obj` without any duplication.

```js
let cars = [{"id":1,"name":"Mercedes","year":"2015"},{"id":2,"name":"Mercedes","year":"2000"},{"id":3,"name":"BMW","year":"2010"},{"id":4,"name":"BMW","year":"2004"},{"id":4,"name":"BMW","year":"2004"},{"id":4,"name":"BMW","year":"2004"},{"id":4,"name":"BMW","year":"2004"},{"id":4,"name":"BMW","year":"2004"},{"id":5,"name":"Volvo","year":"2012"},{"id":6,"name":"Volvo","year":"2014"},{"id":7,"name":"Volvo","year":"2010"},{"id":8,"name":"Toyota","year":"2012"},{"id":8,"name":"Jeep","year":"2011"}];
let obj = {BMW: 6,Jeep: 1,Mercedes: 2,Toyota: 1,Volvo: 3}
let newObj = [];
let duplicateCheck = []
cars.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!duplicateCheck.includes(item.name)) {
    duplicateCheck.push(item.name);
    item.quantity = obj[item.name];
    newObj.push(item);
  }
});
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to come up with the new array, it needs to process by two steps:

1. Keep the first `car` with unique brand from cars array
2. Attach quantity to the `car` from `obj`

```js
let cars=[
  {id:1,name:'Mercedes',year:'2015'},
  {id:2,name:'Mercedes',year:'2000'},
  {id:3,name:'BMW',year:'2010'},
  {id:4,name:'BMW',year:'2004'},
  {id:4,name:'BMW',year:'2004'},
  {id:4,name:'BMW',year:'2004'},
  {id:4,name:'BMW',year:'2004'},
  {id:4,name:'BMW',year:'2004'},
  {id:5,name:'Volvo',year:'2012'},
  {id:6,name:'Volvo',year:'2014'},
  {id:7,name:'Volvo',year:'2010'},
  {id:8,name:'Toyota',year:'2012'},
  {id:8,name:'Jeep',year:'2011'}
];
let obj = {
  BMW:6,
  Jeep:1,
  Mercedes:2,
  Toyota:1,
  Volvo:3,
};

/* The first step:
you can use .filter to 
only return the car you are looking for.
*/
let uniqueCarBrand = [];
let newArray = cars.filter((car) => {
  /* Check if car name already in the newArray */
  if (uniqueCarBrand.indexOf(car.name) >= 0) return false;
  uniqueCarBrand.push(car.name);
  return true;
});

/* Second step:
you will need to attach your quantity to
the array of cars you just created.
*/
let result = newArray.map((car) => {
  /* Check if obj has brand name in it, if not, return 0; */
  car.quantity = obj[car.name] || 0;
  return car;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two loops to match up the objects from both of your arrays:

```js
let output = [];
// For each key in your quantity object
for (let model in obj) {
    // For each car object in your cars array
    for (let car of cars) {
        // This will match the first car in your cars array
        if (car.name === model) {
            // Add quantity to your car object and add it to your result set
            car.quantity = obj[model];
            output.push(car);
            // This break will continue to the next model car to ensure you only have one result per model
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code does not give the desired result, the `output` array is not sorted by `id` element

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 modules

```js
let cars = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2015'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2000'},
  {id: 3, name: 'BMW', year: '2010'},
  {id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
  {id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
  {id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
  {id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
  {id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Volvo', year: '2012'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Volvo', year: '2014'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Volvo', year: '2010'},
  {id: 8, name: 'Toyota', year: '2012'},
  {id: 8, name: 'Jeep', year: '2011'},
];
let obj = {
  BMW: 6,
  Jeep: 1,
  Mercedes: 2,
  Toyota: 1,
  Volvo: 3,
}  

let filteredCar = cars.filter((curr, index) => {
  let _cars = JSON.stringify(curr);
  return index === cars.findIndex(obj => {
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === _cars;
  })
}).map(currCar => {
  currCar.quantity = obj[currCar.name];
                   return currCar});

console.log(filteredCar);
```